# Taking screenshot of video view in live streaming in Android programatically

Tags: android

I have a video view controller in Android activity. I am getting rtsp url from a web server. **I  have to take screenshot of the live streaming video. When i tried i got black screen of video view.** I have been trying and googling this for about three weeks. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Do you have to do this from within you app (Java) or can it be done with adb?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you've already tried?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in solving my problem. I need to do this with in my application (Java) not from adb

Comment: @IrudayaRajLourdhu issue solved ?